# Как запустить polymer CLI?

Tags: javascript, polymer

Возникли проблемы с Polymer Cli. 
Устанавливаю уже 3-й раз, в списке приложений его так и не появляется. Через поиск нахожу файл polymer.cmd , запускаю его, он открывается и через полсекунды закрывается. 
В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: думаю есть смысл предоставить больше подробностей, например вашу ОС, архитектуру ОС, верисию того что вы устанавливаете, описать как именно вы устанавливаете и куда, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить Polymer в переменную окружения Path. (если используете windows)